# No archetype found in remote catalog, Alfresco Maven SDK

Tags: java, maven, alfresco

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/develop/sdk/#gettingstarted

```
java -version
java version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370, mixed mode)

mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.13, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

docker -v
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396
```

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13.

then when I try to generate a new alfresco project I get the following message:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.alfresco:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[INFO] Your filter doesn't match any archetype, so try again with another value.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 47.903 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-26T09:34:02+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please check your filter: `org.alfresco.maven.archetype` see the docs you have linked...  see https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.alfresco.maven.archetype

Comment: Also use a more recent version of Maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise I did try it with Apache Maven 3.8.4 and I got the same message!

Comment: The issue not really the Maven version it's more important that you are using the wrong filter value...

Comment: @khmarbaise I followed the tutorial step by step, I don't where I'm wrong PS: I'm new to Alfresco

Comment: Try with quotes in the Dfilter like this: mvn archetype:generate "-Dfilter=org.alfresco:"

Answer (score 0):

Maven: 3.9.2

Java: Oracle 17.0.2

Run with `-DinteractiveMode=true`

This will allow you to select from the list

`mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=true`